# Delayed execution of Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In my project I have a **modal** window where a cascading dropdownlist is shown for two properties (`Family`, `TypeID`) of a class (`Machine`).

**The issue:**
The dependant dropdownlist populates only when the modal window has been open for the second time. On the first time, nothing happens:

Here is a picture of how it works for a better understanding:

[image]

Notice that the row that says **Modelo** (Modelo is the name for `TypeID`) is empty in the first moment, but once re-opened, it populates with the expected information.

**The code:**

***Note*** The Javascript is located in the Index page that contains the link to the modal window

This modal window is used when a New `Machine` is Created, or Edited.
For that reason, in the first section of the Javascript, I check in which situation I am and check if the `Machine` property: MchName, has a value.
In case it doesn't have a value, I assign the value of the variable `items` to the property `TypeID` that should be shown when the Modal opens.

```
@section scripts{
<script src="~/js/machine-index.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#FamilyID').change(function () {
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Machines/GetModel";
            var ddlsource = "#FamilyID";
            $.getJSON(url, { FamilyID: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
                var items = '';
                $("#TypeID").empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, model) {
                    items += "<option value='" + model.value + "'>" + model.text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#TypeID').html(items);
            });
        });
        $('#modal-action-machine').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            var test = "#MchName";
            if ($(test).val()) {

            } else {
                var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Modelo --</option>";
                $('#TypeID').html(items);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            "autoclose": true,
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    });
</script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
}
```

***Get Method:***

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult CreateEdit(int? id)
    {
        //Lista de Familias
        List<MachineFamily> FamilyList = new List<MachineFamily>();
        FamilyList = (from family in _context.MachineFamilies
                      select family).ToList();
        FamilyList.Insert(0, new MachineFamily { FamilyID = 0, FamilyDescription = "-- Seleccione Familia --" });
        ViewBag.ListofFamily = FamilyList;

        ViewBag.TypeID = string.Empty;
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Machines/_Create.cshtml");
    }
```

***JsonResult:***

```
    public JsonResult GetModel(int FamilyID)
    {
        List<MachineType> ListaModelos = new List<MachineType>();
        ListaModelos = (from model in _context.MachineTypes
                        where model.FamilyID == FamilyID
                        select model).ToList();
        ListaModelos.Insert(0, new MachineType { TypeID = 0, TypeDescription = "-- Seleccione Modelo --" });
        return Json(new SelectList(ListaModelos, "TypeID", "TypeDescription"));
    }
```

***View: Modal***

```
@model Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels.MachineIndexData
@using Application.Models

<form asp-action="CreateEdit" role="form">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ModalHeader", new ModalHeader
{ Heading = String.Format("Actualización de Modelo") })

    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FamilyID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select asp-for="FamilyID" class="form-control"
                        asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.ListofFamily,"FamilyID","FamilyDescription"))"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="TypeID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select asp-for="TypeID" class="form-control"
                        asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.TypeID,"TypeID","TypeDescription"))"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="BrandID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select asp-for="BrandID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.BrandID">
                    <option value="">-- Seleccione Marca --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="BrandID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="SupplierID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select asp-for="SupplierID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.SupplierID">
                    <option value="">-- Seleccione Proveedor --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="SupplierID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="StoreID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select asp-for="StoreID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StoreID">
                    <option value="">-- Seleccione Tienda --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="StoreID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="MchName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="MchName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MchName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="NumDevices" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input id="NumDevices" asp-for="NumDevices" class="form-control" readonly />
                <span asp-validation-for="NumDevices"  class="text-danger"></span>
                <input id="getNum" type="range" min="" max="10" step="1" onchange="fetch()" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FechaCompra" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input data-format="0:dd/MM/yyyy" type="datetime" asp-for="FechaCompra" class="form-control datepicker" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FechaCompra" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CostoMaq" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="CostoMaq" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CostoMaq" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="MachineStatus" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select name="MachineStatus" asp-for="MachineStatus" class="form-control" disabled>
                    <option value="0">Operativo</option>
                    <option value="1" selected="selected">Nuevo Item</option>
                    <option value="2">Reparación</option>
                </select>
                <input type="hidden" name="MachineStatus" value="1" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MachineStatus" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        @await Html.PartialAsync("_ModalFooter", new ModalFooter { })
    </div>
</form>
```

**Final notes:** I believe that to fix this I should change the Javascript. Can someone please explain to me why this happens and how to fix it?

**Update: Attempting to assign a new id to the ´MchName´ field and send it to the Script**

*View:*

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="MchName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input id="MchName2" asp-for="MchName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="MchName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*Script:*

```
        $('#modal-action-machine').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            var test = document.getElementById("MchName2").value;
            if (test) {

            } else {
                var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Modelo --</option>";
                $('#TypeID').html(items);
            }
        });
```

No luck tho.

**Update: Second attempt**

*View:*

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="MchName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10" id="MchName2">
            <input asp-for="MchName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="MchName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*Script:*

```
        $('#modal-action-machine').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            var test = "#MchName2 #MchName";
            if ($(test).val()) {

            } else {
                var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Modelo --</option>";
                $('#TypeID').html(items);
            }
        });
```

Comment: On the first `shown.bs.modal` event, you are defining a `change` event handler... It does not execute, it just gets defined. Then, there probably is a `change` event occuring before the next `shown.bs.modal`... So you see the dropdown.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette That change event is for when the first dropdownlist changes (FamilyID), so the second one updates accordingly. A step prior to that is the script that works on 'shown.bs.modal' that executes when the window opens for the second time. Shouldn't it work on the first time it opens?

Comment: You should create a CodePen to reproduce that issue.

Comment: I don't know what is that. Time to google~

Comment: @LuisAlbertoDelgadodelaFlo, in my answer i give you some real advices, but your error maybe come from another javascript function. Please post your entire javascript part.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Indeed. I just updated my scripts but error still persists. I'm editing the question right now

Comment: `MchName` item it is existing only in the modal ?

Comment: It exists on the Index page too. The Index page shows a table of the Machine model, but, even tho that part of the script is conditioned to this event 'shown.bs.modal', Do you think that is taking in consideration the `MchName` from the Index view and not executing because it is a collection of `MchName` ?

Comment: The index page is in the same page with modal isn't it ?

Comment: The index page has a link that calls the modal. The modal is defined in another file and these scripts are defined in the Index page.

Comment: Yes, I think that..because `asp-for` generate some attributes for your input, for example the id attribute..and you cannot have two elements with same Id attribute because id should be unix..please change one of those with another id.

Comment: ids should be unique.

Comment: Yes, the `asp-for` generates the name (not the id thought I believe). I don't know if I can rename these properties because I need them for the post-action when saving a new `Machine` thru the modal. Could it work if I add a diferent `id`and use that `id`on the javascript? will try it out

Comment: if you use inspect element you can see that is generating the id attribute inclusive

Comment: Oh, and it can't ve overwrited? I tested something. I don't know if it is a valid attempt. Will update it on the question. Thanks for taking your time! Hope we can kill this monster

Comment: When you used `var test = "#MchName"; if ($(test).val())` it found two elements with same id and cannot find the element using selector. You can also use a more specific selector for `MchName` element  from index. For example wrap it in a div :`<div id="myDiv"><input asp-for="MchName"></div>`... and use selector in this way :`var test = "#myDiv #MchName" if ($(test).val()) `.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question and in the last part I show what I believe is what you are recommending, but a little different. Since my attempt didn't work, will try this one.

Comment: Same thing happening in both attemps~

Comment: In your updated `var test=document.getElementById("MchName2").value;` change the condition to `if (test){` instead of `if ($(test).val()) {`

Comment: Updated the question: First attempt section. Changed the code to: `var test = document.getElementById("MchName2").value;
                if (test) {

                }`
Problem persists.

Comment: I put some breakpoints on the code. First time it runs, it does not go thru the if condition. Debug claims: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` Altought the second time it does go thru the conditional and works properly. The second time I open the modal the value is ""

Comment: I believe this happens because the `test` variable is not feeded with a value before the modal opens and since this code executes before the modal loads, it cannot be read and crushes, skipping the if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer that works for this specific case.

The **first** thing that was wrong was evaluate a variable that is not defined inside an `if`statement.

```
$('#modal-action-machine').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    var test = "#MchName";
    if ($(test).val()) {
```

In this code I was assigning the value of `#MchName` to `test`but in a first moment, `#MchName` does not get defined until the modal opens for a first time, and for that, not executing the rest of the code.

**Second:** A turn around was to use click event of the `Create` button to identify if I'm in a case of a New Machine or just an update.

For this I will declare a global variable and assign it the value of zero.
If the Create button is clicked, assign this variable the value of 1, and if this is true, assign the default value that was intended to the `#TypeID` variable.

After the modal closes, re-asign the global variable to zero. This, for the case that another button (Update) is hitted to call the modal.

This is the code:

```
var global = this;
var wasclicked = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {

    document.getElementById("modalbutton").onclick = function () {
        global.wasclicked = 1;
    };

    $('#modal-action-machine').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        global.wasclicked = 0;
    });

    $('#modal-action-machine').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        if (global.wasclicked == 1) {
            var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Modelo --</option>";
            $('#TypeID').html(items);
        }

    });
```

With this, the project works as intended.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap both `shown.bs.modal` event handlers in one single `document.ready` function.

Every time when `shown.bs.modal` event is fired, it will bind a `change` event handler to your `select` element. You should `bind` it only once.

```
script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#FamilyID').change(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Machines/GetModel";
        var ddlsource = "#FamilyID";
        $.getJSON(url, { FamilyID: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
            var items = '';
            $("#TypeID").empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, model) {
                items += "<option value='" + model.value + "'>" + model.text + "</option>";
            });
            $('#TypeID').html(items);
        });
    });
    $('#modal-action-machine').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        var test = "#MchName";
        if ($(test).val()) {

        } else {
            var items = "<option value='0'>Select</option>";
            $('#TypeID').html(items);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your answer is sound, but would you please also consider leveraging the `success` parameter of the ajax asynchronous call?

Comment: @AlexanderDixon, asyncronous method is executed only when he changed the first select element.